# my codeigniter project is not accessing index.php after my project folder name

Tags: codeigniter

my codeigniter project is not accessing index.php after my project folder name
..
http://localhost/projectName/(here index.php is missing)/controllerName/FunctionName

I removed index.php using .htaccess file. But when i inspect source code of navigation bar there were missing index.php in url (eg.

[ब्यूटी](http://localhost/firstproject/Users/newspage/3)).
It is working on localhost but in the live server not working.

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php/$1 [L,QSA] 
i tried but not working
```

Comment: Have you checked $config['base_url'] ?

Comment: yes my base url is $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/firstproject/';

Comment: <li><a href="http://www.foodiespan.com/Users/newspage/2">त्यौहार</a></li>
                                                                                                <li><a href="http://www.foodiespan.com/Users/newspage/3">ब्यूटी</a></li>
                                                                                                <li><a href="http://www.foodiespan.com/Users/newspage/4">रसोई</a></

Comment: You have issue on live url?  If yes then change the base_url of live

Comment: in the live server my base url is domain name

Comment: Check .htaccess file is exist or not in server

Comment: i checked, it's there